# default favicon for a theme?

Tags: theme-development

I am developing a theme and I wonder if there is a possibility to have a default favicon.

Details: The theme already has support for adding favicon and users can go to

```
admin->customize->site identity
```

and select an image for favicon. Is possible that the theme shows a default favicon in case user still hasn't got to it?

Comment: The favicon isn't the theme's business. It should be left to the user to choose based on their needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the defualt Site Icon using the Customizer API.

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'site_icon' , array(
    'default'     => YOUR_IMAGE_URL_HERE,
) );
```